# How to update available products in real time for a ecommerce website

Tags: web, e-commerce

We have an eCommerce application.Let's say an "ItemA" is available and the quantity is 10. Many people are trying to buy the same product. How do we manage the availability of product in the website? When do we remove the product from website. Say, around 8 people are trying to check-out "ItemA". Many might cancel later as well. What is the general strategy that companies follow in this case?

Comment: Here at SO, we help with problems with your code, not with your workflow. If you can provide relevant code, and point to what the problem is, then we can help. See here [mcve]

Comment: The inventory is reduced when the payment transaction is successful.